# Using py_limited_api=cp36 for Python 3.8+ wheel

Tags: python, setuptools, cpython, python-wheel

Let's say I have Python 3.6 on my machine and I can't upgrade it for some particular reason.
I want to build a library for Python >= 3.8 on that machine using `setuptools`. That library also uses the prebuilt C library `c_api_lib`.

My `setup` call looks like this:

```py
options = {'bdist_wheel': {'py_limited_api': 'cp36'} }

setup(
    version='...',
    name='...',
    description='...',
    author='...',
    author_email='...',
    classifiers=[
        'Programming Language :: Python',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.8',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.9',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.10',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.11',
    ],
    python_requires='>=3.8.0',
    ext_modules=[Extension('c_api_lib', [])],
    packages=find_namespace_packages(where='...', include=['c_api_lib']),
    package_dir={"": '...'},
    options=options
)
```

Is that ok to use `py_limited_api=cp36` when the wheel itself can't be installed for Python 3.6? Also, is installing and using that wheel on any Python > 3.8 safe?

Note: I can't use `py_limited_api=cp38` from Python 3.6.